# "Value below was evaluated just now" - React (VibrantJs)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, react, undefined

Olá, pessoal. Estou utilizando a biblioteca [VibrantJS](https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/) passando um array de imagens e guardando o retorno no state do meu componente em React. Como no trecho de código abaixo.

```js
  gerarPaleta = () => {
    let imagens = this.state.imagens;
    let paletaTemp = [];

    for (let i in imagens) {
      Vibrant.from(imagens[i].src.small).getPalette()
      .then((palette) =>
        paletaTemp.push({
          id: i,
          paleta: palette
        })
      );
    }
    this.setState({ paletas: paletaTemp });
    console.log('Paletas: ', this.state.paletas);
  }
```

O problema é que eu não consigo acessar os dados do state `paletas`. Porque retorna uma aviso no console do navegador de

> *Value below was evaluated just now.*

E aparece nessa estrutura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o que eu quero é renderizar a cor em uma div:

```js
render() {
  ...
  let paletas = this.state.paletas;
  ...
  <div className="container">
    {paletas.map((paleta, index) => (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm paleta" style={{background: paletas.paleta.DarkMuted.hex }}>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  ...
}
```

Porém o `map` não roda nenhuma vez, porque o array tá "vazio".

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo de outro jeito:

```js
  gerarPaleta = () => {
    let imagens = this.state.imagens;

    Promise.all(imagens.map(({ src }) =>
      Vibrant.from(src.small).getPalette()))
      .then(
        paletas =>
        this.setState({ paletas })
      )
      .then(
        paletas =>
        console.log("Paletas: ", this.state.paletas)

      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está acessando errado, seria: `paleta.paleta.DarkMuted.hex`, porque no `map` foi colocado `paleta` para trazer cada ***item*** e dentro tem o `id` e o `paleta` e a continuação normal como já mencionado logo acima.

***Exemplo:***

```
render() {
  ...
  let paletas = this.state.paletas;
  ...
  <div className="container">
    {paletas.map((paleta, index) => (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm paleta" 
             style={{background: paleta.paleta.DarkMuted.hex }}>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  ...
}
```

seria bom você renomear então para `item` (*em vez de paleta, pois o próximo objeto é paleta, acho que melhora a leitura do código*) e o exemplo ficaria:

```
render() {
  ...
  let paletas = this.state.paletas;
  ...
  <div className="container">
    {paletas.map((item, index) => (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm paleta" 
             style={{background: item.paleta.DarkMuted.hex }}>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  ...
}
```

---

Simulando:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paletas: []
    };    
  } 
  gerarPaleta = () => {  
    const paletas = this.state.paletas;
    paletas.push({id:1, paleta:{DarkMutet:10}});
    paletas.push({id:2, paleta:{DarkMutet:20}});
    paletas.push({id:3, paleta:{DarkMutet:30}});
    this.setState({paletas});    
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.gerarPaleta();
  }
  render() {
  const paletas = this.state.paletas;
    return (
      <div>
      {paletas.map((item, index) => (
        <div>DarkMutet: {item.paleta.DarkMutet}</div>
      ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```